# Very general object-free categories?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Is there a name for categories $\mathcal C$ such that $\text{Obj}(\mathcal C)$ coinside with $\text{Mor}(\mathcal C)$?

In the diagram below the morphisms are 
$a\overset{a}{\to}a$, $a\overset{b}{\to}c$, $d\overset{c}{\to}c$, 
$a\overset{d}{\to}e$, $e\overset{e}{\to}f$, $c\overset{f}{\to}e$.

[image]

I don't know if this is interesting mathematically. My idea is modelling. In the models all objects should be of the arrow-type in the same category. Nothing in the definition of categories exclude this. Domains and codomains can be defined as usual.

Comment: Do you mean categories where we don't bother naming the objects, or where the set of objects really is equal to the set of morphisms? I think the latter would get intro trouble with specifying domains and codomains (and also I fail to see how it would be more than just labels coinciding).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: the latter.

Comment: Then as I said, I don't see what it means for something to be both an object and a morphism? I mean, in what way would the category change if you relabeled everything to avoid this?

Comment: All categories can be seen as consisting of only morphisms

Comment: @ZelosMalum: How?

Comment: To get rid of the objects, one simply identifies each object with its identity morphism.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Yes, but that wouldn't at all cover all the cases.

Comment: It is true you can eliminate the objects from the formalism of categories, but not in a way to be consistent with the picture in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpreted in a certain way what you are asking is standard. A category  $C$ is a collection $C_1$ together with two maps $s,t:C_1\to C_1$ and a map $m$ from $C_1\times_{\langle s,t\rangle} C_1 =\{(f,g)\,|\,s(f)=t(g)\}$ to $C_1$ satisfying:
$st=t$, $ts=s$, $m(m(f,g),h))=m(f,m(g,h))$ and $m(f,s(f))=f=m(t(f),f)$.
Note that normally we write $m(f,g)=f\circ g$.

To obtain the usual description of category set $C_0=\{f\in C_1\,|\,s(f)=f\}$, keep the same composition, and let the domain and codomain maps $c,d :C_1\to C_0$ be defined by $c(f)=t(f)$ and $d(f)=s(f)$ respectively.

Conversely given a category $C$ forget the set $C_0$, keep the same composition, and let $s$ and $t$ be the maps defined by $t(f) = 1_{c(f)}$ and $s(f)=1_{d(f)}$.

Comment: Yes it is just another description of a category see https://books.google.co.za/books?id=6KPSBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=categories+for+the+working+mathematician&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=arrows-only%20metacategory&f=false page 9

Comment: So any classic representation of a category can be transformed to the questioned representation? And conversely? It seems hard however to recycling knowledge from the classical theory.

Comment: 1. Actually, your definition of $C_0$ is not the right one. $C_0$ should rather be the collection of all two sided *units*. 2. This answer shows only an embedding $C_0\to C_1$, but the OP rather asks about cases with $2|C_0|=|C_1|$.

Comment: @Berci Regarding 1 thanks you are right, I fixed the definition. Regarding 2 I am not sure how you came to the conclusion $2|C_0|=|C_1$?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what precisely you are trying to model, you will need to specify some more axioms. You may then find out you are running into trouble. In any case, you may be interested in monoidal categories, or more generally in 2-categories. There is plenty online to read.

Comment: What kind of trouble? Why couldn't all objects be arrows in the same category?

Comment: @Lehs There is nothing inherently preventing that, but without specifying how the behavior of a morphism changes by being an object, it makes no real difference (and specifying this change is what might cause problems).

Comment: To add: the objects in a category are nothing but slaves serving their morphism lords. Their sole purpose is to act as domain and codomains. It matters not one bit what the objects are. Only the morphisms matter. You seem to want the objects to also matter by demanding them to be morphisms as well. You may do that, but then the question becomes: and now what? Answering that may or may not lead to trouble.

Comment: The difference is that all items in the model should be of the same type.

Comment: You are now being cryptic. You must specify axiomatically what you mean. Or specify your modelling aims. Without that it becomes pholosophy.

Comment: @Lehs There is no such thing as "type" in category theory.

Comment: Read https://books.google.co.za/books?id=6KPSBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=categories+for+the+working+mathematician&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=arrows-only%20metacategory&f=false page 9